# AJAX REST API request

Tags: javascript, ajax, rest, api, get

My problem is that I can not send the correct request to the server to get an answer from him in the form of a json line. 
**Here is my code:**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: url,
    dataType: 'json',
    crossDomain: true,
    username: 'username',
    password: 'password',
    headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    },
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    }
})
```

When I try to send a request, I get an error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load URL. Response to preflight request doesn't
>   pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is
>   present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not
>   allowed access.

Comment: Hi,

Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595515/xmlhttprequest-error-origin-null-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin

Comment: first you forget the data option in your ajax call. second if there is a symatic failure we need to see what the server request should be like, 3rd. allow origin is one of the most searched failure in combination with ajax i think ;) with thousand off google results

Comment: If the front-end app is on a different domain than the one you are requesting from then you should discuss with the guys from back-end how the data should be send cross-domain. If is about CORS then everything is handled by the browser. Remove the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header which is sent by the server. Add "Accept: application/json" to notify the server that data needs to be serialized as JSON. You should reserve some time and read about CORS. It will serve you on the long run. Check this [LINK](http://restlet.com/company/blog/2015/12/15/understanding-and-using-cors/) for example.

Answer (score 0):

```
var dataSet = {
  username: 'username',
  password: 'password',
}

$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: url,
  dataType: 'json',
  crossDomain: true,
  data: dataSet,
  // the origin header has to be set server side
  /* 
  headers: {
   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
  },
  */
  success: function(response) {
    console.log(response);
  }
});
```

parameters have assigned by a dataSet and the option data.
the allow origin header has to be set server side, not in the client